# Find right end-point satisfying an integral constraint

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, boundary-conditions, constraint

I am solving the following system of first-order ODEs with a variable right-end point `l1num` and boundary condition at that point `n[l1num] == l2num`:

```
a1 = 5.85476*10^8;
a2 = 1.24911*10^45;
a3 = 9.648*10^46;

eps0 = 10^-5;

epsilon = {0, 0.03, 0.05, 0.08, 0.10, 0.13, 0.15, 0.18, 0.20, 0.23, 
   0.25, 0.28, 0.30, 0.38, 0.45, 0.55, 0.68, 0.83, 1.00, 1.98, 2.00, 
   2.10, 4.23, 5.10, 5.95, 6.00, 6.05, 7.95, 8.00, 8.05, 10.10, 12.20,
    15.20, 18.20, 23.10, 26.20, 30.90, 37.20, 45.60, 51.00, 63.00, 
   79.00, 80.00, 81.00, 94.00, 95.00, 96.00, 118.00, 149.00, 150.00, 
   151.00, 188.00, 231.00, 284.00, 333.00, 396.00, 483, 584, 715, 895,
    1000};
sigma = {1.26 10^-19, 2.82 10^-20, 1.41 10^-20, 8.71 10^-21, 
   6.21 10^-21, 4.65 10^-21, 3.68 10^-21, 3.02 10^-21, 2.54 10^-21, 
   2.19 10^-21, 1.91 10^-21, 1.69 10^-21, 1.51 10^-21, 2.27 10^-21, 
   3.17 10^-21, 4.58 10^-21, 6.67 10^-21, 9.63 10^-21, 1.37 10^-20, 
   2.67 10^-20, 2.74 10^-20, 2.85 10^-20, 6.10 10^-20, 7.65 10^-20, 
   8.93 10^-20, 9.30 10^-20, 9.08 10^-20, 1.19 10^-19, 1.22 10^-19, 
   1.21 10^-19, 1.40 10^-19, 1.38 10^-19, 1.23 10^-19, 1.02 10^-19, 
   7.66 10^-20, 6.54 10^-20, 5.42 10^-20, 4.43 10^-20, 3.51 10^-20, 
   3.09 10^-20, 2.53 10^-20, 2.02 10^-20, 2.19 10^-20, 1.98 10^-20, 
   1.72 10^-20, 1.74 10^-20, 1.68 10^-20, 1.38 10^-20, 1.11 10^-20, 
   1.14 10^-20, 1.09 10^-20, 9.15 10^-21, 7.63 10^-21, 6.32 10^-21, 
   5.46 10^-21, 4.64 E 10^-21, 3.83 10^-21, 3.18 10^-21, 2.55 10^-21, 
   1.95 10^-21, 1.70 10^-21};
interpolant = Transpose@Join[{epsilon}, {sigma}];
sigma1 = Interpolation[interpolant, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

solODE = NDSolve[{
         n1'[eps] == n[eps], 
         a1 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) + eps sigma1[eps]^2 (a2 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) - a3 eps n[eps]) == 0,
         n1[l1num] == 1, n[l1num] == l2num}, {n, n1}, {eps, eps0, l1num}];
```

The solution of which must satisfy the integral constraint

```
NIntegrate[n[eps], {eps, eps0, l1num}] == 1.
```

I tried to fix `l2num` and store the solution in a table with respect to `l1num`:

```
l2num = 10^-16;
solODE2[l1_] := NDSolve[{
                n1'[eps] == n[eps], 
                a1 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) + eps sigma1[eps]^2 (a2 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) - a3 eps n[eps]) == 0, 
                n1[l1] == 1, n[l1] == l2num}, {n, n1}, {eps, eps0, l1}];

tabl1l2 = Table[Abs[1 - NIntegrate[Evaluate[n[eps] /. solODE2[l1]], {eps, eps0, l1}]], {l1, 10, 20, .001}];
```

Then,

```
Min[tabl1l2] = 0.745373
```

Thus, in this way, I can get some very rough solution, but it takes a long time since I need a finer division in table.

I also tried to locate the required value using `FindRoot':

```
FindRoot[1 - NIntegrate[Evaluate[n[eps] /. solODE2[l1]], {eps, eps0, l1}], {l1, 10}]
```

which results in

```
NDSolve::ndsv: Cannot find starting value for the variable n.
```

Any idea is highly appreciated.

**Update**

I think, it will be more appropriate to change the problem statement as follows. How to solve the following ODE

```
solODEred = NDSolve[{a1 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) + eps sigma1[eps]^2 (a2 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) - a3 eps n[eps]) == 0,
            n[l1num] == l2num}, {n, n1}, {eps, eps0, l1num}];
```

such that its solution satisfies the integral constraint:

```
NIntegrate[n[eps], {eps, eps0, l1num}] == 1.
```

We can fix `l2num = 10^-16`. We can even fix `l1num` (that would be even better). Apparently, the addition of a new equation `n1[eps] == n[eps]` and corresponding condition `n1[l1num] == 1` is not of much help.

Comment: Differentiating the integral constraint gives `D[Integrate[n[eps], {eps, eps0, l1num}], l1num]==n[l1num]==0` , perhaps in contradiction to `n[l1num]==l2num`?

Comment: Well, `l2num` should be very small, for instance, of `10^-16` order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the constants defined as in the question, compute

```
{s1, s2} = NDSolveValue[{n1'[eps] == n[eps], a1 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) + 
    eps sigma1[eps]^2 (a2 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) - a3 eps n[eps]) == 0, 
    n1[eps0] == 0, n[eps0] == 1}, {n, n1}, {eps, eps0, 12}];
```

which differs from the computation given in the question by the boundary conditions, `n1[eps0] == 0, n[eps0] == 1` and the upper bound on the integration.  Because the ODEs are linear, this computation determines the desired values of `n` and `n1` (which is the integral of `n`)) up to the same multiplicative constant.  In other words, the computation above gives the desired value for `s1[eps]/s2[eps]`, and `s1[l1num]/s2[l1num] == l2num` determines `l1num`.  Ploting

```
LogPlot[s1[eps]/s2[eps], {eps, eps0, 12}, ImageSize -> Large, 
    AxesLabel -> {eps, n/n1}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

we find that the result has inadequate precision.  To eliminate this difficulty, `Rationalize` all constants (e.g., `a1 = Rationalize[5.85476*10^8, 0];`, include the option, `WorkingPrecision -> 30` in `NDSolve`, and repeat the computation to obtain

[image]

With the added precision, we obtain the desired

```
FindRoot[s1[l1num]/s2[l1num] == l2num, {l1num, 8}]
(* {l1num -> 10.0917} *)
```

**Addendum: More direct but much slower solutions**

Defining `solODE2` as in the question but with `WorkingPrecision -> 40, MaxSteps -> 30000` allows more direct but much slower computations.

```
FindRoot[NIntegrate[n[eps] /. solODE2[l1], {eps, eps0, l1},
    WorkingPrecision -> 30, PrecisionGoal -> 6] == 1, {l1,8}, Evaluated -> False]
```

or, more simply but still slow,

```
FindRoot[n1[eps0] /. solODE2[l1], {l1, 8}, Evaluated -> False]
```

both yield the earlier result, `{l1num -> 10.0917}`.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. So, I run the code

`l2num = 10^-16;`
`{s1, s2} = NDSolveValue[{n1'[eps] == n[eps], a1 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) + eps sigma1[eps]^2 (a2 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) - a3 eps n[eps]) == 0, n1[eps0] == 0, n[eps0] == 1}, {n, n1}, {eps, eps0, 12}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];`
`l1numFR = l1num /. FindRoot[s1[l1num]/s2[l1num] == l2num, {l1num, 8}];`

and it indeed finds a root.

Comment: However, when I enter the root into the initial system:
`l2num = 10^-16;`
`solODE2[l1_] := NDSolve[{n1'[eps] == n[eps], a1 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) + eps sigma1[eps]^2 (a2 (n[eps] - 2 eps n'[eps]) - a3 eps n[eps]) == 0, n1[l1] == 1, n[l1] == l2num}, {n, n1}, {eps, eps0, l1}, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];`
the solution does not satisfy the integral constraint.

Comment: In fact, `NIntegrate[Evaluate[s1[eps]], {eps, eps0, l1numFR}] == 4688.49`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision`.  The precision is inadequate, as shown in my first plot.  `Rationalize` all constants and use `WorkingPrecision -> 30`.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: Strange, as I change values of `a1, a2, a3`, `FindRoot` throws an error
`InterpolatingFunction: Input value {-82} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used`. I put the constraint `{l1num, 8, 12}` inside `FindRoot`, get the same.

Comment: Replace `12` by a larger number in `{eps, eps0, 12}` in the first block of code in my answer.  Specifically, choose a number for the upper limit of integration that is somewhat larger than your expected `l1num`.

Comment: I did so. I used `50` and also `100`. Same error.

Comment: I changed `a1 = 5.85476*^-28`, `a2 = 1.24911*^9` and `a3 = 9.648*^10` and it works well. However, when I set `a2 = 1.24911*^10` and `a3 = 9.648*^11` (`a1` is the same), I get the error mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: Plotting `s1[eps]/s2[eps]` shows that the answer must be around `6`, so use that as a guess.  `FindRoot[s1[eps]/s2[eps] == l2num, {eps, 6}]` yields `{eps -> 5.97056}`.  Always plot the curve you are working with to see what a good initial guess would be.  Also, note that the plot is nonsense for `eps > 7` due to insufficient precision.  Unfortunately, increasing `WorkingPrecision` beyond about `45` often leads to internal errors that are beyond the user's control.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and effort. So, can we claim that, in general (since I will need to run it for over 40 different values of `a1, a2, a3`), the first root will be the actual solution? In that case, I could simply use `{l1num, 0}` in `FindRoot`, correct?

Comment: `l1num > eps0` is necessary.  Maybe try something like `FindRoot[s1[eps]/s2[eps] == l2num, {eps, 100 eps0}]` or `FindRoot[s1[eps]/s2[eps] == l2num, {eps, 10 eps0, 20 eps0}]`.  It may take some experimentation.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for your help.